# Custom SRS for openlayers 3 (ol3) without an EPSG code

Tags: openlayers, proj, well-known-text, coordinate-system

How can openlayers 3 be told to use and work with a custom SRS-definition which has no EPSG-code?

May i don't understand it but it seems like ol3 needs an EPSG- or ESRI-code
to work.

I found some examples about how to use WKT- and proj4- definitions unsing Prof4js.defs, but it didn't work for me:

Proj4: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29027295/how-to-use-openlayers-3-with-proj4js

[OpenLayers 3 transform coordinates to custom projection](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217600/openlayers-3-transform-coordinates-to-custom-projection)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29302770/parsing-projection-wkt-in-openlayers-3

I had several errors caused by the line with the definition (`proj4.defs`) saying the projection is undefined. I used a WKT and a proj4 declaration in there - both were creating the same Error.

I have a WKT- and a simple proj4-definition for the needed reference body, but i don't understand how to combine it to make it work in ol3.

The simplified js I use:

```
var baseLayers = new ol.layer.Group({
    title: 'Base Layers',
        openInLayerSwitcher: true,
        layers:
        [   new ol.layer.Tile({
                title: "testLayer1",
                baseLayer: true,
                source: new ol.source.OSM({                     
                    url: 'tiled_layer1/{z}/{x}/{-y}.png'
                })
            }),
            new ol.layer.Tile({
                title: "mos_final_14_02_13.map",
                baseLayer: true,
                visible: false,
                source: new ol.source.OSM({                     
                    url: 'tiled_layer2/{z}/{x}/{-y}.png'
                })
            })
        ]
    });
var overlays = new ol.layer.Group({
    title: 'moasaic single frames',
        openInLayerSwitcher: true,
        layers:
        [   new ol.layer.Tile({
                title: "overlay1",
                baseLayer: false,
                source: new ol.source.OSM({                     
                    url: 'tiled_overlay/{z}/{x}/{-y}.png'
                })
            }),
            new ol.layer.Tile({
                title: "overlay2,
                baseLayer: false,
                visible: false,
                source: new ol.source.OSM({
                    url: 'tiled_overlay2/{z}/{x}/{-y}.png'
                })
            })
        ]
    });         
    var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
            center: ol.proj.transform([0, 0], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
            zoom: 3,
            minZoom: 0,
            maxZoom: 9
        }),
        controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([
            new ol.control.LayerSwitcher()
        ]),
        layers: [baseLayers, overlays]          
    });
```

OpenLayers 3 Examples showing this: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.3.0/examples/wms-image-custom-proj.html

They use a JS-file telling the Definition for the Projection - but i didn't find the place where they use it - its just standing in thier souce-code.

Answer (score 1):

They use it in this file http://openlayers.org/en/v3.3.0/examples/wms-image-custom-proj.js

You have to add your custom projection

proj4.defs("EPSG:21781","+proj=somerc +lat_0=46.95240555555556 +lon_0=7.439583333333333 +k_0=1 +x_0=600000 +y_0=200000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=660.077,13.551,369.344,2.484,1.783,2.939,5.66 +units=m +no_defs");

Then use it for your view, as in wms-image-custom-proj.js

Comment: I tried that and had a look for this post, too:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/29303807

I used both mentioned methods with proj4.js and wkt declarations in script and in a js-file. It took me a while to fix the errors but, the used layers aren't at thier position like they should - nothing changed.

I am using several geotiffs which are tiled by gdal2tiles. The geotiffs are using the wanted projection and are shown at thier position in Arcmap. My used command-line is like:
gdal2tiles -p raster -r near -z 0-9 input.tiff output/dir

Comment: it seems like gdal doesn't work with exotic projections. It wants 

-p PROFILE with mercator or geodetic - default 'mercator' (Google Maps compatible). Are there any hints or advises how to import an own srs to gdal???
I used -p raster which will create tiles without any srs - the result is such a tiled picture.
How can i add a srs and profile to use it by "-p my_sphere"

Answer (score 1):

for my knowledge it should work with using this in head

```
<script src="js/proj4.js"></script>
<script src="js/my_sphere_proj4.js"</script>
```

and writing this into map.js:

```
var projection = ol.proj.get('my_sphere');
```

now we should be able to use the my_sphere_proj4.js file:

```
proj4.defs("my_spehere","+proj=longlat +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=12345 +b=12345 +units=m +no_defs");
```

which can written into the js of the map or can be loaded by the 'my_sphere_proj4.js' above, wright?

the map itself is written like this:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.transform([0,0], 'EPSG:4326', 'my_sphere'),
    zoom: 2,
    minZoom: 0,
    maxZoom: 8
}),
controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([    
    new ol.control.LayerSwitcher()
]),
layers: [ my.layer,s ]
});
```

All i got now is an visual Error - the map is shown like in mercator-projection but it should look like (wgs84) an equidistand projection.

If i use 'projection' with 'epsg:4326' and 'center: 0,0' its shown normal but its using the Earth.
If i use it with 'my_sphere" its not showing anything and the debugging in firefox tells: "TypeError: a is null" in ol3.js 30:23, which is openlayers3.

Idk how to fix that now.